# get facebook post list of a specific user with a third part app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Do you know if is there any way to collect last user's post on personal wall/timeline?
I need to know how many and which youtube videos has been shared by an user, reading them from his open graph profile.

I've never wrote any facebook app, but using the Open Graph Explorer seems that this kind of information is available if the user has set to "public" the privacy options of a post that contains a Youtube video.

My question is: could a third party app ask for the permission to read that kind of information? Could it have access to these posts also if they are not set as "public" by their owners?

EDIT: Could an app have access to user's posts like another friend of that user?

Comment: If its set to public, yes you could view their wall. If its not set as Public, and you are not authorized as a Friend or the User, then no, there is no way. 

In Short: don't rely on Public information, because the % of users that keep everything Public is very small. I personally would not build an app that relied on that.

Comment: Thank you @TommyCrush: but is possibile to write an app that ask for access to personal posts? I don't want to rely on public info (I know that are very infrequent). In other words, could the app read that info like another friend of the user can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the user's wall by creating an app with the `read_stream` permission and after the user grant you access by hitting the `me/feed` [connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). But creating a 'listening' tool app is not recommended, if your app has no value for its users then you may need to rethink your app mission.